# Official documentation of #available?

Tags: swift

I googled all over the place. I just can't find the official page on https://developer.apple.com discussing `#available` in detail.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple won't have documentation for `#available` since this is a language (Swift) feature.

Here it is: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/statements/#Availability-Condition

In addition people confuse an attribute `@available` (can only be used in declaration) with the keyword `#available` (can only be used in a condition to perform a run-time check). They are not the same thing!

Comment: NOTE: The updated link is https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/statements/#Availability-Condition